# Sitecore.ContentSearch Search by Field Value

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

How do I get a sitecore item in Sitecore 7.2 by its field (of type droptree) value using Sitecore.ContentSearch?

I've tried: `context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().FirstOrDefault(resultItem=>resultItem["Field Name"]=="{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}");` but no luck. Any tips?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guids get indexed in a normalized format (lower case, no hyphens or braces). So if you want to search in this way, I think you need to normalize your search term.

See the 'slightly complex queries' section of this blog post:
http://www.xcentium.com/blog/2013/11/05/sitecore-7-linq-to-sitecore-simplified-part-1

By the way, if you do your query using a mapped POCO's rather than SearchResultItem then you can avoid having to manually do that normalization.

Comment: The provided link is no longer available.

Comment: Updated my answer to include the new URL

Answer (score 1):

Try The following:

```cs
context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().FirstOrDefault(resultItem=>resultItem["Field Name"]== Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.IdHelper.NormalizeGuid("{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}");
```

Or just like martin suggested, you can create your own POCO class which have a property of your field with type (Sitecore.Data.ID):

```cs
public class MyOwnPoco : SearchResultItem
{
    public Sitecore.Data.ID MyField {get;set;}

}

context.GetQueryable<>().FirstOrDefault(i=> i.MyField == Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse("{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}"));
```